# childbrowser will not open

Tags: cordova, childbrowser

I have installed an example of childbrowser on my device. Source code can be found here:

https://github.com/Icenium/sample-childbrowser.git

After the app run No childbrowser is opening. I haven't changed anything with the code, so I'm sure the problem is not with the code. I've tried other childbrowser examples and non of them open a childbrowser either.

I know this is extremely vague, so I'm not expecting direct answers. I would just like to ask some tips or suggestions, where to start solving my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new version of Icenium Ion on the App Store that supports the ChildBrowser plugin. However, you need to uninstall Ion and make a clean install to make it work. For some reason an upgrade doesn't enable plugins.

Still no support in the simulator, though.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Whizkid747 mentioned, if you are working with Icenium and cannot get the plugin to work it is probably because at this moment the ChildBrowser is not supported in the Icenium Simulator - nor in Ion.

It appears the only way to get it working is to provision it to a real device, without the use of Ion. More information [on the Icenium forum](http://icenium.com/community/forums/icenium-general-discussion/childbrowser#1qJoJ4OtrEmgg-ujgwNF8Q).

Do note, there is an open [feature request](https://feedback.telerik.com/Project/87/Feedback/Details/1066-support-for-childbrowser-in-simulator-or-ion) for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need childbrowser for phonegap(I am assuming this is correct as you have tagged the post with phonegap), use it from this link: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser . The link you have provided is for Telerik Icenium Childr Browser plugin.

If incase you need the plugin for Telerik Icenium, please tag the question with Telerik and change the title to show that you need help with Icenium so that some Telerik experts can help you.